# latex figure figure* order

Tags: floats, two-column, starred-version

I am writing a journal which has two column. I am using {figure} as well as {figure*} to place the figures in one column as well as stretch across two columns.

My problem is the order of the figures are not correct. e.g. their order of appearance is:

```
                Figure 1.
                Figure 2.
                Figure 5.
                Figure 3.
                Figure 4.
```

What should I do to make them appear in order?

Comment: Try the package `fixltx2e`.

Comment: You could try to force the position of the figures by adding the options `[h]` or even `[H]` to the `figure` environment.

Comment: See also: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  @UlrikeFischer your suggestion works.. thanks. If you post this as an answer i can select it as a best answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the package `fixltx2e`. It contains a fix for the "1-col fig can come before earlier 2-col fig"-bug.

Comment: Got some conflicts. I replaced subfigure with subfig and changed all the \subfigure to \subfloat. It now works. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed in the 2015 LaTeX release and the `fixltx2e` package is no longer required (in fact the package does nothing now, all the fixes that it used to apply have been incorporated into the main latex code)